# Setting up coc.nvim for python

Tags: python, vim, neovim, coc.nvim

I have installed [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) and extension [coc-python](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python)(:CocInstall coc-python)

When I opened file I refused of linting and then get error:

```
[coc.nvim] Jedi error: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                File "completion.py", line 694, in <module>
[coc.nvim] Jedi error: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      
[coc.nvim] Jedi error:     import jedi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jedi'
```

I tried to reinstall extension and plugin but It doesn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's recommended to use https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright if you're using Python 3, or use https://github.com/pappasam/coc-jedi if you're using Jedi.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you don't have the `jedi` package installed for your python interpreter. I would expect it to work after you run (in your command line)

```
pip3 install jedi
```

I have also just seen that I installed the `pynvim` package in my python environment as well but I don't remember whether you need this.

Answer (score 2):

When I started to edit .py file there were some notification but cause I was typing the notification was skipped and then it showed me `[coc.nvim] Jedi error: import Jedi`.

It turns out the notification asked me to select a python interpreter (I had two interpreters: one from anaconda and second from python.org). While I installed Jedi to 'python.org' interpreter, I didn't install Jedi to anaconda's python interpreter and hadn't selected which python interpreter to use.

So you should do either:

1. Select a python interpreter when prompted.
2. If there's no prompt then manually select python interpreter:

`:CocCommand python.setInterpreter "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonVersion\python.EXE"`

or
`:CocCommand python.setInterpreter "/usr/bin/python3"`

And don't forget actually install Jedi: `pip install jedi`

Answer (score 1):

YMMV but I got past that exact error by adding this to my :CocConfig  `"python.jediEnabled": false`

Comment: can you still use stuff like go-to definition after doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is answer on the github:

https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/193

Answer (score 0):

To solve a similar problem I did the two following actions:

1. Install the last version of jedi:

   `pip install jedi --upgrade`
2. Set the Coc Python interpreter to the version of Python I use (and for which jedi is installed)

   In the C:\Users\myuser.vim\Coc-Settings.json make sure the following line is present

   `"python.pythonPath" : "C:\\Python36_x64",`

   Where "C:\Python36_x64" is the path of my Python interpreter

Remark: The Coc-Settings.json file is not in C:\Users\myuser\vimfiles (gVim) nor in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\nvim (NeoVim) like the :CocConfig command would let you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by adding "python.pythonPath": "python3" to your coc-settings.json file.

If you are like me and uses lots of python virtual env or conda env then do the following:

1. Disable Jedi

```
$ vim ~/.config/coc/extensions/node_modules/coc-python/package.json
"python.jediEnabled": false,
```

2. Set following to you `:CocConfig` to solve the no interpreter issue.

```
"python", {
\   'jediEnabled': v:false,
\   'pythonPath': split(execute('!which python'), '\n')[-1]
\ }
```

Hope this helps ~